# WSL doesn't redirect me to google chrome

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In order for my script to run successfully, I need to insert the URL of the site that the API redirected me to. Everything works in my Windows Powershell, I run my code and my Google Chrome tab opens, I successfully copy the address and you're done. But when I run this code on WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) absolutely nothing happens. Perhaps he has some permissions to use Chrome? He certainly has access to the Internet.

I tried searching for "Chrome WSL Access" but didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Can you add the code you're running? What happens if you execute the path to chrome directly `/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe`?

Comment: Well, I work with the Spotify API. There doesn't seem to be anything in the code that it can depend on. Yes, when I launch Chrome, the Chrome tab is launched directly.

Comment: Please add a minimal reproduce of your problem - we have no chance of understanding your problem without more details.

Comment: I get the message: "Enter the URL you were redirected to:". In the spotipy library scripts, I found in which case this message is printed: `def _get_auth_response_interactive(self, open_browser=False):
        if open_browser:
            self._open_auth_url()
            prompt = "Enter the URL you were redirected to: "`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all requested information or clarification to the question. Don't use comments for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're running some code that eventually calls the [spotipy/oauth2.py#L432](https://github.com/spotipy-dev/spotipy/blob/master/spotipy/oauth2.py#L432), which has this line in it:

```
def _open_auth_url(self):
    ...
    webbrowser.open(auth_url)
    ...
```

I suspect the issue is due to `webbrowser` not currently working with WSL, which is tracked in this issue:
https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89752

You could try to see if you achieve what you want non-interactively. There seems to be some methods including a `open_browser` parameter, which you can perhaps set to `False` somewhere.